# Dell laptop screen brightness is not working after upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, dell, brightness, function-keys

I tried with

```
GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

but did not worked.Please help me out

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using? Also please provide more information such as laptop model number and any fixes you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1273234

The answer from Antonio worked for me. I have a dell vostro laptop as well.

Rafa

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.